# iOS widgets not refreshing

Tags: ios, widget, today-extension

My application has a widget which should display latest news. But it is always showing new content when user goes into the app and refreshes it's content. I have implemented both widgetPerfomrUpdateWithComplationHandler and viewDidAppear to display the new content.

My app registers itself for Push notifications.Is there anything I need to implement in the code or there is an issue on the server side?

Here's my code :

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [self.articleTableView reloadData];
}
-(void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
    [self.articleEntitiesArray removeAllObjects];
    self.articleEntitiesArray = nil;
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return kHeightCell;
}
- (void)widgetPerformUpdateWithCompletionHandler:(void (^)(NCUpdateResult))completionHandler {
    // Perform any setup necessary in order to update the view.
    // If an error is encountered, use NCUpdateResultFailed
    // If there's no update required, use NCUpdateResultNoData
    // If there's an update, use NCUpdateResultNewData

    [self fetchAndStoreContentsForList:nil completionHandler:^(NSError *error) {
    if(error != nil) {
        [self.articleTableView reloadData] ;
        completionHandler(NCUpdateResultNewData);
    }
    else {
        self.unableToLoadErrorLbl.hidden = YES;
        [self.activityIndicator stopAnimating];
        self.activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true;
        completionHandler(NCUpdateResultNoData);
    }
    }];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad I figured it out the URL's I was hitting fetched no data.